# ASP.NET MVC. Error calling action + repository from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to show my ViewModel in modal by using jQuery `.load` unfortunatelly I got error 500 when trying to do so, because when modal window created, it sent empty ViewModel to repository. How may I avoid this?
Here is jQuery in View:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $('#content').load('/Home/Create');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(AddRecordViewModel addrecord)
{
    if (addrecord != null)
    {
       _recordRepositiory.AddMessage(addrecord); 
    }          
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

So on here Repository:

```
public void AddMessage(AddRecordViewModel model)
{
    var userip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    var useragent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
    var a = new Users
    {
        UserName = model.UserName,
        Email = model.Email
    };
    _db.Users.Add(a);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    var b = new Messages
    {
        Message = model.Message,
        UserId = a.Id,
        UserAgent = useragent,
        UserIP = userip,
        Added = DateTime.Now
    };
    _db.Messages.Add(b);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You can divide your code using `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()){ }`

Comment: If the request is ajax you shoud return something different like a view or json data...and if your AddRecordViewModel is empty, you can initialize it with dummie data, can you describe your escenario a little bit more, please?

Comment: Additionally to what I said - I'm using jQuery function to load Create View. This view called via jquery from another view - Index. Then I'm using ViewModel - AddRecordViewModel to pass custom set of data to the repository.

Comment: What if you do this: `if (addrecord != null)
            {
               _recordRepositiory.AddMessage(addrecord); 
            } else{ addrecord = new AddRecordViewModel(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should have 2 create methods - one action returns just the view decorated with [HttpGet] attribute, the other accepts the viewmodel and has [HttpPost] attribute. Your DAL logic goes in the latter.

Example:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View("Create", new AddRecordViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AddRecordViewModel addrecord)
    {
        if (addrecord != null)
        {
           _recordRepositiory.AddMessage(addrecord); 
        }          
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```